# tensorflow import error with CUDA

Tags: tensorflow

I have problems import Tensorflow with gpu backend.
I always get the same error.
Can anybody help?

```
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


    Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

    See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

    for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
    above this error message when asking for help.
```